# Validate Xml node with XPath

Tags: xml, validation, xpath

Aside of using XSD, is it possible to validate that all `<AAA>` nodes contain `<BBB`> with XPath?

For example, I need to verify that count of //AAA/CCC = count of //AAA

I need to do this in one expression, if it's possible

```
<root>
  <AAA>
    <CCC/>
  </AAA>
  <AAA>
    <BBB/>
  </AAA>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that in my code there is a simple validation of selected nodes count
against 0, I happened to have answered the question by myself:

```
//AAA[not(CCC)]
```

which gives 1 nodes count, that is validation successfully fails as expected.